Google Pub Sub working on local, not working on production
I want to develop a system to get notifications for google business review. I set up google business sign in with appropriate scopes. I went through documentation and was able to pull from a subscription, into a node js server i made. It worked on local as intended. I pushed it to Production, but i found it is not working
async function pubsubReview() {
  const starNum = (str) => {
    str = str.toUpperCase();
    if (str == "ONE" || str == "STAR_RATING_UNSPECIFIED") {
      return 1;
    } else if (str == "TWO") return 2;
    else if (str == "THREE") return 3;
    else if (str == "FOUR") return 4;
    return 5;
  };
  try {
    const [subs] = await pubSubClient.getSubscriptions();
    console.log("Subscriptions:");
    subs.forEach((s) => console.log(s.name));

    const subscription = pubSubClient.subscription(subscriptionNameOrId);

    // Receive callbacks for new messages on the subscription
    subscription.on("message", async (message) => {
      await message.ackWithResponse();

      console.log("Received message:", message.data.toString());
      try {
        console.log("\n\n", JSON.parse(message.data.toString()), "\n\n");
        const noti = JSON.parse(message.data.toString());
        const accountName = noti.location.split("/locations")[0];
        const reviewName = noti.review;

        const review_name_parts = reviewName.split("/");

        const location_name = review_name_parts[2] + "/" + review_name_parts[3];

        const query = `

        SELECT c.company_id, st.page_token, st.selected_template_url, st.enable_bg, c.location_ids FROM
        (SELECT location_ids, company_id FROM google_my_business WHERE account_name = '${accountName}' ) c
        JOIN 
        (SELECT * FROM socials_token ) st
        ON
        c.company_id = st.company_id


         
      `;

        const queryRes = await promiseQuery(query);
        const pageToken = queryRes[0].page_token;
        const companyId = queryRes[0].company_id;
        let enable_bg = queryRes[0].enable_bg;

        const locationsAddedCheckQuery = `SELECT locations_added FROM google_my_business WHERE company_id = ${companyId}`;
        const locationsAddedCheckQueryRes = await promiseQuery(
          locationsAddedCheckQuery
        );
        let locationsAddedCheck =
          locationsAddedCheckQueryRes[0].locations_added;
        if (!locationsAddedCheck) {
          return res
            .status(200)
            .send({ data: "[]", success: true, toggle: false });
        }

        let toggleCheck = `SELECT location_ids FROM google_my_business WHERE company_id = ${companyId}`;
        let toggleCheckRes = await promiseQuery(toggleCheck);
        toggleCheck = JSON.parse(toggleCheckRes[0].location_ids);
        toggleCheck = toggleCheck.filter((item) => {
          return item.toggle && item.name == location_name;
        });

        console.log("\n\ntoggle Check is\n", toggleCheck);

        if (toggleCheck.length > 0) {
          console.log("\n\ntrying to make post to fb\n");
          try {
            const reviewData = await fetchReview(reviewName, companyId);
            const revieweeName = reviewData.reviewer.displayName;
            const reviewText = reviewData.comment;
            const stars = starNum(reviewData.starRating);
            if (stars >= 4) {
              let templateUrl = queryRes[0].selected_template_url;

              console.log("\n", templateUrl, "\n", pageToken, "\n");
              const response = await axios.get(templateUrl, {
                responseType: "arraybuffer",
              });
              const bufferTemp = Buffer.from(response.data, "binary");
              let image = await Jimp.read(bufferTemp);
              let buffer = null;
              if (enable_bg) {
                buffer = await generateReviewImageWithBG(
                  image,
                  stars,
                  revieweeName,
                  reviewText
                );
              } else {
                buffer = await generateReviewImage(
                  image,
                  stars,
                  revieweeName,
                  reviewText
                );
              }
              const publicUrl = await uploadToGCP(buffer, reviewName);
              console.log(
                "\n\nreview created successfully\n",
                publicUrl,
                "\n\n"
              );
              const imgPost = await postImageToFB(
                pageToken,
                publicUrl,
                "demo-post"
              );
              await deleteFromGCP(reviewName);
              console.log("\n\nposted review to  FB and deleted from GCP");
            }
          } catch (err) {
            console.log("\n\nfailed to make post with error\n", err, "\n\n");
            throw err; // Rethrow the error to be caught in the listener's catch block
          }
        } else {
          console.log("\n\nwill not post to fb\n\n");
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("\nGot error While running PubSub Listener\n", err, "\n\n");
      }
    });

    // Receive callbacks for errors on the subscription
    subscription.on("error", (error) => {
      console.error("Received error:", error);
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("\n\n", err, "\n\n");
  }
}

pubsubReview();

I did this code, I only get posts on FB only when Im running server on my own PC.

Can you be more specific? Are you getting errors in production? What is your production environment?

I had set up console logs for testing. these logs come when i run server locally. the server in production isnt really working as all new review are acknowledged only in local and not in production
